# grep Everything after a string

Tags: grep

I need to only grep the md5 hash

this is the hash

```
MD5 (mt.pm) = adcddd9492c707642d2bcffbfc67b7a6
```

it needs to look like this

```
adcddd9492c707642d2bcffbfc67b7a6
```

or to do the reverse

crapb0c63a3cb776502fe03706b2fd540439 /home/mta.pm"

and only get the hash 
now clue how to 
any Help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grep out substring which can change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340835/how-to-grep-out-substring-which-can-change)

Answer (score 0):

To grep, do the following (this will not work in all [grep implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2239/grep-1/index.html)):

```
grep -o '[a-z0-9]*$'
```

or you can use sed:

```
sed 's/.*= *\([a-z0-9]*\)$/\1/'
```

Comment: omg thanks works prefect ...how do you learn all of these crazy switches and regex to do this

Comment: The answer is, you learn them once (or rather: you learn them all the time), and you can apply them almost anywhere in almost the same form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (`GNU grep`):

```
grep -oP '.* \K.*$'
```

Or better :

```
grep -o '[[:xdigit:]]\{32\}$'
```

Or with `bash` :

```
read -a arr <<< 'MD5 (mt.pm) = adcddd9492c707642d2bcffbfc67b7a6'
echo ${arr[-1]}
```

---

With `\{32\}` it's much stronger. `md5` is always 32 hexadecimal characters, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

---

`[[:xdigit:]]` is a [POSIX class regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), that means to match only hex chars.

---

**FINALLY**

If you want to match a 32 hex characters long in a string :

```
grep -o '[[:xdigit:]]\{32\}'
```

will do the trick.

Comment: what about before b0c63a3cb776502fe03706b2fd540439  /home/ma.pm

Comment: what about to only get the hash before like only the hash

Comment: This is not your use-case AFAIK !?

Comment: But that do the trick : `echo 'MD5 (mt.pm) = adcddd9492c707642d2bcffbfc67b7a6  /home/ma.pm' | grep -o '[[:xdigit:]]\{32\}'`

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. You can 'accept' the reply too by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackoverflow website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackoverflow works, thanks ;)