# How to grep out substring which can change?

Tags: grep

Basically I have a very large text file and each line contains

```
tag=yyyyy;id=xxxxx;db_ref=zzzzz;
```

What I want is to grep out the id, but the id can change in length and form, I was wondering if its possible to use grep -o and then grep for "id=" then extract everything that comes after it until the semicolon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
$ grep -o 'id=[^;]*' file
```

And if you don't want to inlcude the `id=` part you can using positive [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=id=)[^;]*' file
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
grep -Po "(?<=id=)[^;]*" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Via grep:

```
grep -o 'id=[^;]*'
```

Via awk:

```
awk -F';' '{ print $2}' testlog
id=xxxxx
```

edit: see sudo_O's answer for the look-behind.  it's more to the point of your question, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this awk. It should also work if there are multiple id= entries per line and it would not give a false positive for `...;pid=blabla;...`

```
awk '/^id=/' RS=\; file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
grep -oP 'id=\K[^;]*' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/id=([^\;]*);/)' your_file
```

tested:

```
> echo "tag=yyyyy;id=xxxxx;db_ref=zzzzz; "|perl -lne 'print $1 if(/id=([^\;]*);/)'
xxxxx
>
```