# Don't output first grep search term

Tags: regex, bash

So I have the following in a file:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/blah/blah.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password"
```

and I am using the following command:

```
cat file.txt | grep -Eo "Store=[^ ]*.jks"
```

and getting

```
Store=/home/blah/blah.jks
```

How can I do just get:

```
/home/blah/blah.jks
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grep out substring which can change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340835/how-to-grep-out-substring-which-can-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\K` from the perl extension.

```
$ grep -oP 'Store=\K[^ ]*.jks' file.txt 
/home/blah/blah.jks
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sed` instead, and edit the match on the fly:

```
sed -rn 's/^.+Store=([^ ]*.jks).*$/\1/p' file.txt
```

The `-n` option suppresses printing, and the `p` command after the substitution switches it back on, but only for the matched lines. The `-r` option means an easier-to-use regex engine.

By the way. Don't pipe `cat` into these Unix utilities (grep, sed, tr, awk, etc). They all understand filenames as the last arguments. One process is always better than 2 processes.